# Java http delete request to delete an item from a repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, http-delete

I am trying to create `java` code to delete an item from a repository in a `spring boot` server using the item's ID.

My server code:

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteUser/{id}")
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id){
    userRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Java client code to connect to server:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1234/deleteUser");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                     
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE");   
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

For my other requests of `get` and `post` I would use the output stream to write to the server, but I am not sure the exact code to send the ID that needs to be deleted to the server

Comment: Update `URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1234/deleteUser");` to `URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1234/deleteUser/id-to-be-deleted");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` is a path variable, you must pass it as one. For example:

```
http://localhost:1234/deleteUser/42
```

I suggest you use Spring's `RestTemplate`, which offers the `RestTemplate#delete(String url, Map<String, ?> uriVariables)` [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#delete-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-):

```java
new RestTemplate().delete("http://localhost:1234/deleteUser/{id}", Collections.singletonMap("id", 42));
```

Comment: Bear in mind that RestTemplate is in maintaince mode as of Spring 5 and WebClient is the replacement https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

Comment: @JoshVandeWalle Definitely a good mention. I guess reactive is the future...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebTesClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#webtestclient) like this :

```
@Autowired
protected WebTestClient webTestClient;

webTestClient.delete()
             .uri("http://localhost:1234/deleteUser/{id}", YOUR_ID)
             .exchange()
             .expectStatus().isOk();
```

Don't forget to add `webflux` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```